# how open links inside a .load jquery page without reloading page

Tags: jquery, ajax, pagination

I have the jquery code below which updates the query when I click on a checkbox, everything works great my only problem is the page I have loaded has a pagination and when I click next or one of the pagination links they refresh the page and lose the search. I was wondering if there was a way to open the links inside the page without the page reloading. if not what would be the best way to go about paginating the data. Thanks

here is my jquery code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".remember_cb").click(function () {
        var action = $("#criteria").attr('action');
        var form_data = $('#criteria').serialize();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: action,
            data: form_data,
            beforeSend: function () {
                $('#loading').html('<center><img src="/images/loading8.gif" alt="Loading..." align="absmiddle"/></center>').fadeIn('fast');
            },
            success: function (data) {
                $("#loading").fadeIn('fast');
                $('#exercise_list').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
                $("#loading").fadeOut('slow');
            }
        });
    });
    return false;
});
```

If you need me to include any other code please let me know. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

When a normal link is clicked, it triggers navigation to whatever URL is in its `href`. You're going to have to prevent the navigation behavior, but still trigger some JS that will re-populate your search results with the next page of data. You can do both in the button's `click` event handler:

```
var page = 1; //the page number we're currently on

$('a.nextPage').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); //stops navigation to the URL in the link

    var input = $('#criteria input[name="page"]'); 
    if (!input.length) {
       input = $('<input>', {type:'hidden', name:'page'}).appendTo("#criteria");
    }

    input.val(++page);

    var action = $("#criteria").attr('action');
    var form_data = $("#criteria").serialize();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: form_data,
        beforeSend: function () {
            $('#loading').html('<center><img src="/images/loading8.gif" alt="Loading..." align="absmiddle"/></center>').fadeIn('fast');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            $('#exercise_list').html(data).fadeIn('slow');
            $("#loading").fadeOut('slow');
        }
    });
});
```

This code is just an example, but hopefully you get the idea. I'd also get rid of this line from your `success` function:

```
$("#loading").fadeIn('fast');
```

That will probably produce a weird visual effect, since your loading indicator is already visible. Also, small detail, but the `<center>` tag has been deprecated for a while. Just use a center-aligned div.

Comment: Hi @Justin Morgan, thanks for the example I should be able to work it out now. Much appreciated.

Comment: @FitnessFreak - Glad I could help! If this answer was helpful to you, please click the green checkmark to accept it.